# Nodejs memcached module to remove all the keys based on the namespaces

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memcached

I am trying to integrate the memcahed module in node js for accessing the data from memcahe server.In this the key i am using a mongodb query as a string to store data in memcache server.If there was any update operation done in mongo db , i want to remove the all the keys related to that collection but the query strings are different.Is there any possibe way to remove all the keys based on the namespaces, wildcards from the memcached server.

Answer (score 1):

There is no range operations that I am aware of in memcache (although there was an [indication](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/RangeOps) that some implementations of memcached servers provide those). With the standard memcached server you have to identify each and every key and delete it one by one individually.